# Nginx 2 rewrites for 2 cases

Tags: nginx

I did not found any usefull information for my case.

I'm trying to do 2 nginx rewrites to handle 2 specific case for a website :

- If a user goes directly to URL 1, then i "internally" rewrite URL 1 to URL 2 (URL2 with parameters, not URL 1), but still display URL 1 to the client
- If a user goes on URL 2 instead, i redirect him to URL 1, and then i want my first rule to be applied again.

So i have this :

```
#URL 2
location ~ /URL/2 {
        rewrite /URL/2?id=5406 https://$host/URL/1 redirect;
} 
#URL 1
location ~ /URL/1 {
        rewrite /URL/1 /URL/2?id=5406 last;
}
```

It returns me a 404 not found.

The usecase : i have an application where url are not "pretty". So i want nginx to be capable of handling pretty urls if called, and i also want him to redirect to pretty URL if wrong URLs are called.

Thanks the community if you can help me out,

Happy coding anyway,

B.

**EDIT:** URL 1 rewrite is working properly when i remove the URL 2 rewrite ...

Comment: You have created a loop. If `/URL/2` can be processed within the same `location` block, use `rewrite...break` instead of `rewrite...last`.

Comment: Hi there, first thank you for your help. I tried to change last to "break", perhaps i'm still getting 404 :/

Comment: The other way to break the loop is to redirect using `$request_uri`, for example: `if ($request_uri = "/URL/2?id=5406") { return 302 /URL/1$is_args$args; }`

Comment: Top ! It's working using $request_uri. Perhaps, i got to swap again to "last" in this case. Thanks a lot for your help, hours saved ! :)